# App crashes on pressing back while question is loading

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

This happens once every two or three times.

On navigating to a question from the feed, and pressing back while the question is loading crashes the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, it's now fixed and will go out in a future update.